# CEdit::ModifyStyle(), dosallow 0 when es_number is set inside CDialog::OnInitDialog

Tags: visual-c++

I have an edit control which should only take integers betweeen 1 and 99.To achieve this, i used, modifystyle() and limittext().Is there a way to restrict 0 from being entered?

Comment: Also adding to it,is there a way that es_number be overwritten such that it doesnt take the number 0?

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to control values limit it using your code.
It is easier if you subclass (add variable) edit control using wizard, you can choose UINT type and set minimum and maximum value here.
Also do nto forget to set style to ES_NUMBER (setting Number to True in edit control Properties).

Comment: I already have a variable(assigned in DoDataExchange()) holding the value in EditBox.This is of UINT type. To the Spincontrol,is the Editcontrol(which I'm working on). I already did use CSpinButtonCtrl::SetRange(1, 99) but that works only for the SpinCOntrol , how do I manage the EditControl?

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely need that, you must derive a class from `CEdit` and process the input accordingly. Rendering the baloon that says "Unacceptable Character" may be bit tricky to give *online-error*. The class would be useful only if you are planning to use such class (edit-control) at multiple places, preferably with different ranges.

Comment: The only range to it is between 1 and 99.Would there be any other alternate to it to restrict entering the value 0 in the edit box?

Comment: You may attach a spin-button control (CSpinButtonCtrl) with the edit-control. And/or you may handle EN_CHANGE notification. But what if use enters "20" and then tries to make it "30" by deleting "2" and then entering "3" ?

Answer (score 0):

This is completely different problem from than one in your original post.

Make sure that your spin control follows immediately edit control in the Z-order (tab order).
In the resource set spinner style to: UDS_AUTOBUDDY UDS_SETBUDDYINT, UDS_ALIGNRIGHT,.
This will causse spinner to: choose edit control as buddy, set integer in edit box, place itself inside edit control to the right edge.

To do that, in the properties for the spinner set: "Auto Buddy" True, "Set Buddy Integer" True and "Alingment" to Right Align.

You do nto have to set minimum and maximum for the edit control, handle it now in the command handler for EN_CHANGE notification.

Place this code in the handler.

```
void CYourDlg::OnEnChangeEditNum()
{
    int iValue = GetDlgItemInt(IDC_EDIT1);
    if(iValue < 1 || iValue > 99)
    {
        m_Edit.ShowBalloonTip(_T("Number Out of Range"), _T("Value must fall between 1 and 99."), TTI_INFO_LARGE);
    }

}
```